# What bitness is Mountain Lion kernel, because `uname -p` returns `i386`?

Tags: macos, kernel

I know, the answer should be 64, as Apple dropped support even for their early 64 bit models BUT:

```
Nathan-der-Graue:~ max$ uname -p
i386
```

while on the other hand:
[image]

Could someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per: http://lists.apple.com/archives/Darwin-dev/2009/Aug/msg00211.html

You want `uname -m` rather than `uname -p` to determine the bitness of the kernel.

```
$ uname -m
x86_64
```